# Check if value is between two timestamps 24 times(1 day in hours) in R

Tags: r, timestamp, intervals, between

The code will be used to check if a 1 hourly interval is within timestamp1 and timestamp2. However, for every id and corresponding timestamps this needs to do it 24 times (0:00:000 till 23:00:000). So every id should give 24 results with TRUE or FALSE. The code doesnt match the given intervals(between timestamp1 and timestamp2). How do i fix this?

```
id <- c(1, 2 ,3 ,4 ,5)
timestamp1 <- structure(c(1618725826, 1618808778, 1618981628, 1619070713, 1619070218
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")

timestamp2 <- structure(c(1618745800, 1618819480, 1618999145, 1619082202, 1619081591
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")

matching_hours <- rep(F, 24)
names(matching_hours) <- 0:23

results <- lapply(id, function(id) {
  matching_hours[as.POSIXlt(timestamp1[id])$hour:as.POSIXlt(timestamp2[id])$hour] <- T
  matching_hours
})

results
```

Afterwards i made it into a table:

```
results <- lapply(id, function(id) {
  matching_hours[as.POSIXlt(timestamp1[id])$hour:as.POSIXlt(timestamp2[id])$hour] <- T
  data.table(t(matching_hours))
})

results <- rbindlist(results)
```

Small side note:
corresponding timestamps means id:1 corresponds with 1618725826(timestamp1) and 1618745800(timestamp2)

Answer (score 0):

A small addition can get you the expected output.

Since the names of vector start from zero and indexing in R starts from 1.

```
timestamp1[1]

[1] "2021-04-18 11:33:46 IST"

timestamp2[1]

[1] "2021-04-18 17:06:40 IST"

as.POSIXlt(timestamp1[1])$hour:as.POSIXlt(timestamp2[1])$hour

[1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17

matching_hours[as.POSIXlt(timestamp1[1])$hour:as.POSIXlt(timestamp2[1])$hour]

   10    11    12    13    14    15    16 
FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

By adding 1 to the sequence will give you the expected output

```
matching_hours[(as.POSIXlt(timestamp1[1])$hour:as.POSIXlt(timestamp2[1])$hour) + 1]

   11    12    13    14    15    16    17 
FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

To get the results in data.frame object below code will be helpful:

```
results <- do.call('rbind', results)

results

         0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10   11   12   13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20    21    22    23
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```